# How to set the same width between custom UITableViewCells and UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I created several cells with Interface Builder, and I'm using them to fill a UITableView. In other words, I have 3 classes for 3 different kinds of cell, and an other view which contains a UITableView.

**- My UITableView containing different kinds of cells :**
[image]

**Here's my problem :**
On the iPhone emulator, it looks great. But on the iPad emulator, **the custom cells width is fixed**. The UITableView width fits to the screen width, so it's good, but the UITableViewCells does not fit to the UITableView. **I want to force the custom UITableViewCells to take the UITableView width.**

Is there anything to do in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`method, where I instanciate my custom cells ?
Or do I have to write a thing like `self.fitToParent;` in the custom cells header file ?

***EDIT (schema) :***

[image]

***EDIT 2 (cellForRowAtIndexPath method) :***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifierType1 = @"cellType1";
    static NSString *cellIdentifierType2 = @"cellType2";
    NSString *currentObjectId = [[myTab objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] type];

    // Cell type 1
    if ([currentObjectId isEqualToString:type1])
    {
        CelluleType1 *celluleType1 = (CelluleType1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierType1];

        if(celluleType1 == nil)
            celluleType1 = [[CelluleType1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierType1];

        celluleType1.lblAuteur.text = @"Type1";

        return celluleType1;
    }

    // Cell type 2
    else if ([currentObjectId isEqualToString:type2])
    {
        CelluleType2 *celluleType2 = (CelluleType2 *)[tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierType2];

        if(celluleType2 == nil)
            celluleType2 = [[CelluleType2 alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierType2];

        celluleType2.lblAuteur.text = @"Type2";

        return celluleType2;
    }
    else
        return nil;
}
}
```

Comment: want to make universal app?

Comment: Did you try using AutoLayout in the custom cells xib?

Comment: Yes, I set two constraints : one on the left, the other on the right. But it only impacts the content of the cell, not the cell itself. In other words, my custom cell has a predefined width, because I set it in IB. AutoLayout can't do anything on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem using the following code in each custom cell class. It's not very clean, but I can't spend one more day on this issue...

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect contentViewFrame = self.contentView.frame;
    contentViewFrame.size.width = myTableView.bounds.size.width;
    self.contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
}
```

Thank you for your help **KudoCC**.

Comment: How did you get **myTableView** reference in **custom cell class**?

Comment: @ZaidPathan At that time, I put the tableView in an ugly global variable. I think the more proper way to do this is to design all the cells in Interface Builder actually...

Answer (score 0):

I think uitableviewcell's width is the same as the tableview's width.You can try to set cell's background color to test it. `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor] ;`

You should create a class which inherit from UITableViewCell and override it's method `- (void)layoutSubviews` , adjust your content's frame there.

Comment: No, uitableviewcell's width is not the same as the tableview's width. I've already a class for each cell type, but I don't know what to write in their `- (void)layoutSubviews` method to adjust their size to tableView. Please see the picture I've added in my question.

Comment: Your tableviewcell is loaded by xib?

Comment: How do you know your tableviewcell's width is not the same as the tableview's width?

Comment: Yes, I have a xib for each cell type, associated with its own class (example for first cell : "cellType1.h", "CellType1.m", "CellType1.xib").
I know that the widths are not the same because when I launch the emulator, I obtain the result that I schematize in my edit (there is a background color for each cell).

Comment: You'll find the cellForRowAtIndexPath method in my **edit 2**.

Comment: please try this code `celluleType1.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor] ;` , I still think the cell's width will equal to tableview's width.

Comment: Code above is not enough , I think it's very weird if their width is different.

Comment: I confirm, their widths are different ! I think it's because I set up the custom cells into IB. Please see this illustration to see what I want to say : [illustration](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v6vy1.png).

Comment: I think system will extend your tableviewcell's width automatically , that is why the delegate only have `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` no `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView widthForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

Comment: I hope you can upload your project to github so that We can help you to solve that.

Comment: I can't upload it because it's a confidential project... Sorry

Comment: You can create a new demo project and do the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
// anything you write in this section is taken with respect to default frame of width 320.
}
```

awakeFromNib is called when [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; is processed- anything you write in  section is taken with respect to default frame of width 320.
You need to make another custom function and call it after cell gets initialized.
For eg:-

```
@implementation CheckinTableViewCell{
    UILabel *NameLabel;
    UILabel *rollLabel;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    rollLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    [self.contentView addSubview:NameLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:rollLabel];

}

-(void) bindView{
    NameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.contentView.frame.size.width-20, 20);
    rollLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, NameLabel.frame.size.width, 20);
}
```

and call this function in tableview cellForRowAtIndex:-

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CheckinTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell ==nil){
        cell = [[CheckinTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

        cell.name = @"Harry";
        cell.rollno = @"123456";

        [cell bindView];

    return cell;
}
```